# How to remove space between two containers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have two Containers of height 250 inside Column widget. There is no any other widget present between this two Container widget but still I can see very little space between two containers.

Here's my code...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = 250;
    TextStyle containerTextStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: height,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Container 1', style: containerTextStyle),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: height,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Container 2', style: containerTextStyle),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know why but if I set the height of this containers to 100 or 400 it is not showing any space between container. Did not try with many different values for height but space is visible for some value and not visible for other value.

Here's the screenshot from my phone...

**Both Containers height is equal to 250**
[image: containers with height 250]

**Both Containers height is equal to 400**
[image: containers with height 400]

Comment: Ran your code and I don't see any spaces at 250/350/450. Try adding black border to the containers. `decoration: new BoxDecoration(
border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black))`

Answer (score 4):

Replace your scaffold with this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.black),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Container 1', style: containerTextStyle),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.black),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Container 2', style: containerTextStyle),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

As @sukhi said,
You need to use the `BoxDecoration` in your `Container`.

But Rather than giving border Color you can simple set width of border to 0.

Like Below:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    border: Border.all(width: 0),
  ),
  height: height,
  child: Center(
    child: Text('Container 1', style: containerTextStyle),
  ),
),
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    border: Border.all(width: 0),
  ),
  height: height,
  child: Center(
    child: Text('Container 2', style: containerTextStyle),
  ),
),
```

And Do not forget to give your color inside `BoxDecoration` instead of `Container` itself else it will throw an error.

```dart
Cannot provide both a color and a decoration
The color argument is just a shorthand for "decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: color)".
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but currently seems to be an open Flutter issue. My solution was similar to other answers, but as the color in my case had opacity, I had to wrap the problematic container with another container, and add the decoration to the parent container:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.black, //the color of the main container
             border: Border.all(
               //apply border to only that side where the line is appearing i.e. top | bottom | right | left.
               width: 2.0, //depends on the width of the unintended line
               color: Colors.black,
             ),
           ),
```

As suggested from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288#issuecomment-668795963

Comment: what is the problematic one in here? if I have two containers in a column, how do I know the problematic one? wrap both of them?