# Flutter How to remove line between two widget in stack?

Tags: flutter, containers

I have found this kind of question from below
[How to remove space between two containers in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283035/how-to-remove-space-between-two-containers-in-flutter)

but，their background color is simple color ,eg black color,
If the two container were set different color, the line still there.

[image]
[image]

code snippet:

```
return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        // 蓝天(背景)
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: widget.backgroundColor,
        ),
       
        // 中间云朵
        Positioned(
          bottom: -2.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: centerCloudHeight,
              child: Image.memory(
                _cloudsCenterBytes,
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I added decoration, but no effect:

```
      Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 0,
              color: widget.backgroundColor,
            ),
            color: widget.backgroundColor,
          ),
        ),
```

here is source code : https://github.com/xuelongqy/flutter_easyrefresh/blob/v2/lib/taurus_header.dart

How to fixed this, please give me some tips , thanks

Comment: Are you sure your image doesn't have a row of transparent pixels on the edge? When I try an example with two containers it looks fine.

Comment: you remind me, I'm going to make sure， thank you

Comment: that "bottom: -2" could mean that you see the color of a widget above or below the container